# Find length of key in vigenere cipher

Tags: cryptography, vigenere

I am new to cryptography kindly help to solve the following vigenere cipher problem with well defined steps

Assume you are given a 300 character encrypted message, encrypted in Vigenere cryptosystem, in which you know the plaintext word CRYPTOGRAPHY occurs exactly two times, and we know that the ciphertext sequence TICRMQUIRTJR is the encryption of CRYPTOGRAPHY.  The first occurrence starts at character position 10 and second at character position 241 (we start counting from 1).  What is the length of the key used for encryption

Comment: OK, we know what the question is.  We don't know what you have tried in order to answer the question.  Show us what you have tried and we can give you pointers.  If you do not even attempt the question then we won't even attempt to help you.  Stackoverflow helps those who help (or at least try) themselves.  Perhaps you need to ask your instructor for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is 7 
Solution To estimate the period we use the Kasiski test. The distance between the two occurrences given is
241 − 10 = 231 = 3 · 7 · 11
positions.
Possible periods are thus 3, 7 and 11. If the guess is correct, we can immediately find the
corresponding shifts: at position 10 the shift is
T − c = 19 − 2 = 17 = r
. Similar computations for the other positions gives the shift keys
rrectcorrect
We now see that this is not periodic with periods 3 or 11, while period 7 is possible. The keyword
of length 7 starts at position 15; hence the keyword is
correct.